# getting weird error while using angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

First I define an array:

```
$scope.workspaces = [{name: "Traffic Permits", state: "traffic-permits", classname: "tab_table ng-isolate-scope"}];
```

then I call it:

```
<a class="{{workspace.classname}}" ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" 
                 ui-sref="{{workspace.state}}" ui-sref-active="active">{{workspace.name}}
            </a>
```

Seens pretty straightforward. I am just declaring a menu basically. However I am getting a strange error:

```
TypeError: a.hashPrefix is not a function
    at Object.href (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:11776)
    at Object.y.href (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:19457)
    at link.t (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:24512)
    at link (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:24721)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular.js:6711:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular.js:6105:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular.js:6001:30)
    at $get.boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular.js:6125:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular.js:6732:18)
    at ngRepeatAction (http://localhost:51188/Scripts/angular.js:20624:15) <a class="{{workspace.classname}} ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="workspace in workspaces" ui-sref="{{workspace.state}}" ui-sref-active="active">
```

All help is appreciated thanks.

```
angular.module('myModule').config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //
    // For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/traffic-permits");
    //
    // Now set up the states
    $stateProvider
    .state('traffic-permits', {
        url: "/traffic-permits",
        templateUrl: "/admin/permittable"
    });
});
```

Ok, so I am now using the unminified version of the router. The error is being thrown at:

```
url = "#" + $locationProvider.hashPrefix() + url;
```

The error is `$locationProvider.hashPrefix() is not a function`, what could this be???

I put a break point there. hashPrefix is an empty string.

Comment: Do you have something going on with `htl5mode`? [This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q04gLz12) is not throwing any errors. Is there more to know?

Comment: @salniro Thanks for the response. I haven't specified anything with html5mode... hmmm....

Comment: @salniro I added my routes. Perhaps there is something wrong with those? They look alright to me....

Answer (score 0):

Hash prefix is not a property - you use it to set the hash prefix.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#-location-service-configuration

Comment: Right, I am not saying that it is supposed to be a  property. I am saying that when I put a break point there IT IS a property and that is why this error is being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

apparently somebody thought it was a good idea to add this in the module config:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix = '';
```

ridiculous....